# Swagger codegen generated code misses method for certain media type

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to build a REST api versioned by mediatypes using Swagger 3. I want to return different objects depending on the accept header within the request.

So I created a yaml file in http://editor.swagger.io and generated the server code (jaxrs-cxf). But the generated code always only contains a method for the first object type.

I broke it down to a fairly simple yaml file. When generating the server code, only one method is generated:

```
openapi: 3.0.6
info:
  title: pet test api
  description: testapi for mime based versioning
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://animal.com/pets
paths:
  /pet:
    get:
      tags: 
        - pets
      summary: pets
      description: get cat or dog
      responses: 
        '200':
          description: get specific pet
          content:
            application/cat+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/cat'
            application/dog+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/dog'
components:
  schemas:
    cat:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        name:
          type: string
    dog:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        age:
          type: integer
```

My expectation would be to get at least two methods generated within main/java/io.swagger.api.impl.PetsApiServiceImpl.java

```java
public class PetsApiServiceImpl implements PetsApi {
    /**
     * pets
     *
     * get cat or dog
     *
     */
public Cat petGet() {
        // TODO: Implement...

        return null;
    }

public Dog petGet() {
        // TODO: Implement...

        return null;
    }
}
```

But actually only one method is being generated:

```java
public class PetsApiServiceImpl implements PetsApi {
    /**
     * pets
     *
     * get cat or dog
     *
     */
    public Cat petGet() {
        // TODO: Implement...

        return null;
    }

}
```

To be honest, this is the first time I use swagger.

So is my expectation wrong, and what I want to archive is simply not possible? Or is this a bug within the swagger codegen?

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Open an issue in the Swagger Codegen repository at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues. Also, there's no `openapi: 3.0.6`, the latest version so far is `3.0.2`

Comment: Thanks Helen! Changed openapi: 3.0.2 (obviously without any impact). Also opened an issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/9322